# Configuration object is coming as null in Test Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

//I have a controller class where my configuration file UserConfig is autowired. I am trying to test the method verifyEmail where it has logic to fetch some configuration properites from yml "userConfig.getRedirect().getMobileSuccessRedirectURL();"

```
@RestController
public class UserVerificationControllerV1 {

    @Autowired
    private UserConfig userConfig;

     @GetMapping("/email")
    public void verifyEmail(Device device, String token, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

       ....
       ....

        if (device.isMobile()) {
            successRedirectURL = userConfig.getRedirect().getMobileSuccessRedirectURL();
           }
        ....
        ....
        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
    }
```

//When I am trying to run test case the configuration object is showing null in test class as well as controller class. I am not sure what wrong I am doing. Please find the controller class and the test class.

```
 @WebAppConfiguration("src/main/resources")
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {UserConfig.class, DeviceConfig.class})
    public class UserVerificationControllerV1Test {

        @InjectMocks
        private UserVerificationControllerV1 userVerificationControllerV1 = new UserVerificationControllerV1();

        @Autowired
        private UserConfig cfg;
@BeforeEach
    public void beforeTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        //initializeConfig();
    }

    @Test
    public void getDevice_Mobile() throws Exception {
        .....
        ......
        userVerificationControllerV1.verifyEmail(device, "123456",response);
        List<String> responseList = response.getHeaders("Location");

        assertEquals(MOBILE_URL, responseList.get(0));
    }
```

Comment: Ofcourse it is, you aren't running with the spring dedicated runner and are using mocked controller. Even if you would run with the dedicated runner it would be null in the controller because you create it yourself (and basically render the `@Autowired` useless).

Comment: I need to use mocked controller as there are service calls which I dont require. Also removing the @Autowired private UserConfig cfg; sentence still produces null in the controller class. Please advice!

Comment: Again read... It will be `null` as well (as I stated). I strongly suggest a read of [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans) and following a [guide on the matter](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) instead of messing around.